# Can I sort (question accroding to ) recently answered &/or accepted question?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, answered-questions

I want to sort question on the basis of recently answered question on askubuntu. Such as newest,frequent,unanswered, Can I sort by following?:

- **Recently Answered Questions**
- **Recently Accepted Answers**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost possible to have what you need, using the search functionality.

- **Recently Answered Questions**
  The following query would search for all answers and sort them by the newest answer.
  https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aanswer
- **Recently Accepted Answers**
  The next query would search for all answers which are accepted and sort them by the newest answer.
  https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aanswer%20isaccepted%3ayes

Also following options can help you:
[image]